# Get width and height of LibGdx animation

Tags: java, libgdx

How can I get the width and height of a single frame when using LibGdx Animation?

```
tallAnim = new Animation(1/10f, atlas.findRegion("runner1"), atlas.findRegion("runner2"), atlas.findRegion("runner3"), atlas.findRegion("runner4"));
shortAnim = new Animation(1/10f, atlas.findRegion("short_runner1"), atlas.findRegion("short_runner2"), atlas.findRegion("short_runner3"), atlas.findRegion("short_runner4"));
animation = tallAnim;
```

I switch between these two animations and when I check for collision I need to know if the exact width/height of the current animation frame.

How I'd normally handle this:

```
public Rectangle getBounds(){
return new Rectangle(positionX, positionY, sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `atlas.findRegion("path/goes/here")` returns a TextureRegion. A TextureRegion has a `region.getTexture()` method. A Texture has a `tex.getWidth()` and a `tex.getHeight()` method. Assuming these frames are the same width, you should be able to just say something like `atlas.findRegion("path/goes/here").getTexture().getWidth()` and `atlas.findRegion("path/goes/here").getTexture().getHeight()`. Otherwise you'll need some way to keep track of what frame your on and get the width and height depending on the current frame.

Your method, I'm guessing, should now look something like:

```
public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(posX, posY, atlas.findRegion("path/goes/here").getTexture().getWidth(), atlas.findRegion("path/goes/here").getTexture().getHeight())
}
```

I'll provide some links to each of the classes, so you can look through yourself and see what other methods they have.

TextureAtlas documentation: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.html

TextureRegion documentation: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html

Texture documentation: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html

Comment: there is no `.getRegion` or `.getTexture` in `TextureAtlas`.

Comment: Whoops, I meant `findRegion` in my question when I was referring to the TextureAtlas. However, findRegion() returns a TextureRegion, and TextureRegion _does_ have `getTexture`. Are you getting any errors? Please post them if you are.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can do `findRegion.getTexture().getWidth()`, but this returns the width of the entire atlas. There seems to be no way to get a specific region. You can not `getTexture()` from that.

Comment: I tried: `return new Rectangle(posX, posY, atlas.findRegion("runner1").getTexture().getWidth(), atlas.findRegion("runner1").getTexture().getHeight());`. I have a temporary fix right now where I set a textureRegion in the constructor and just use that instead, works as long as frames are same size. But not pretty

Comment: You could try using `createSprite()` create a sprite from a specific region, and getting the width and height of the sprite. This can also allow for more flexibility later on, since Sprites are a lot more powerful than textures.

Comment: Or if you really want it that way the `getRegionWidth()` and `getRegionHeight()` from a TextureRegion `atlas.findRegion("runner1").getRegionWidth()` should work. Because when you get the texture and the width/height of it, it is indeed the whole atlas dimension.